# Object Orientated Search function PHP

Tags: php, search, mysqli

Hi I am trying to create a search function using OOP PHP however when I run my query and enter false data I am still getting results. Results that are not in the database.

I feel like I am lacking something in my code,

Perhaps my query is wrong I'm not sure as I am new to the whole programming aspect.

Any help would be welcomed!

index.php

```
  <?php
 include("classes/class.House.inc"); 
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>UndergradPad</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="bodyWrapper">
 <div id"header">
 <img id="banner" alt="UnderGradPad Logo" src="images/banner.png"/>
 </div> <!-- End header -->

 <div id="search">
<h1>Find student accomodation</h1><br/>
<p> Location  </p>
    <form method="post" action="search.php" name="search" id="searchform">
    <input type="text" name="term" id="searchinput"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value=""/>
    </form>
 <div class="help">e.g. 'PO5' or 'Portsmouth'</div>
 </div> <!--End search -->
 </body>
 </html>
```

classes/class.House.inc

```
  <?php 
     include("connect/class.Database.inc");

    class House extends Database {

     public function search (){

        $query = "SELECT * FROM houses WHERE postcode like '%$term%'";

                $result = $this->mysqli->query($query);

                $num_result = $result->num_rows;    
                if($num_result > 0){
                    while($rows =$result->fetch_assoc()){               
                        $this->data[]=$rows;
                        //print_r($rows);
                    }           
                    return $this->data;
            } 
    } else {
        echo 'No Records Found';    
        }
             } }
 ?>
```

Comment: $term does exist in the scope of the search method... when you call search(), pass it as an argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point, the `$term` variable is not defined.

You may have meant `$_POST['term']`? This is the global variable that PHP defines for posted data.

However, I would suggest having the variable as an argument on the function, as it will give you the flexibility to use it without relying on the post data.

eg:

```
function Search($term) {
    // now you can use $term as a local variable within the function.
}
```

...and in the code where you call it, pass `$_POST['term']` as a parameter. Use something like this:

```
$houseobject->Search($_POST['term']);
```

Secondly, you need to escape your SQL data, otherwise you are at risk of SQL injection. Since you are using the MySQLi classes for DB access, there are two approaches here: escape the variable yourself, or use Parameterised Queries and let MySQLi do the work for you.

- Escaping it yourself:

  ```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM houses WHERE postcode like '%".$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($term)."%'";
  $result = $this->mysqli->query($query);
  ```
- Parameterised Queries:

  ```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM houses WHERE postcode like ?";  // ? placeholder in query
  $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bind_param("s", "%$term%");       // insert your variable into the placeholder (still need to add % wildcards)
  $stmt->execute();
  ```

  See [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for more info on prepared statements.

Parameterised queries are considered the more secure and more modern approach, but either way will work just fine. You must do one or the other though; without them, your program will break as soon as someone enters a quote mark in the code, and it could easily be used to hack the site.

One final point: Wildcard searches in SQL using a `%` at both ends of the string are extremely slow. You'll be okay if you DB is small, but as it grows, the query will get progressively slower and slower. If you expect to have more than a few hundred records in the table, you should seriously consider alternative searching methods. (there are a number of options here, depending on your needs, so I won't go into them now, but do a bit of research and see what is best for you).

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Sprudley, thanks for that answer its really informative. I've tried your solution however I am now getting this error: 
`Warning: Missing argument 1 for House::search(), called in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/undergradpad/search.php on line 25 and defined in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/undergradpad/classes/class.House.inc on line 23`  where have i gone wrong?

Comment: @Gurtarandeep - since you've specified the parameter in the Search function declaration, you need to also specify it when you call the function. I mentioned this in the answer -- pass the post variable into the function, like so: `$obj->Search($_POST['term'])` where `$obj` is the House object you've already created.

Comment: i see thats working perfectly now apart from this error message `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/undergradpad/search.php on line 26` this only happens when the query is returned as false. what does this mean

Comment: @Gurtarandeep - `foreach` will throw this error if you loop it on something that isn't an array. In this case, you need to make sure the array is initialised even if you don't have any results. But this is getting off the original topic now, and it's hard to answer further big questions in comments like this. If you have further problems, you might want to ask them as separate questions.

Comment: ok i will do post a new question thank you for your help! very much appreciated